# Backbone Marionette Module Order of Initializers

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have been looking at Backbone Marionette for sometime, have been mimicking parts of it for my own pure Backbone application. Looks really promising, but 1 thing that I am not sure about is the Modules structure and order in which initializers run. Mainly regarding `Backbone.history.start`

I am thinking I will have a top level `Application` that contains modules like `Auth`, `Todo`, `Comments` etc (I usually start with a simple todo app to try out frameworks). Each module will have its own routes. In my understanding, they will have to be initialized before I do `Backbone.history.start()`. Do I just trigger all modules to start in my top level `Application`, then start history? This will ensure module routers are initialized before starting `Backbone.history`. This sounds like starting potentially unneeded modules, thus slowing down the app?

Of course, most apps I know, don't need to be very large, do startup speed is probably acceptable. However I wonder whats the best practice or recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Modules start with the parent application by default, but you can override this:

> A sub-module can override this behavior by setting it's
>   startWithParent to false. This prevents it from being started by the
>   parent's start call.

You can then call `MyApp.MyModule.start()` manually whenever you'd like.

When you call `Application.start()`, modules are run in reverse order. From the [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#starting-and-stopping-modules):

> Starting of sub-modules is done in a depth-first hierarchy traversal.
>   That is, a hierarchy of Foo.Bar.Baz will start Baz first, then Bar,
>   and finally `Foo.

You'll want to call `Backbone.history.start()` after calling `Application.start()`, with at least one router instantiated in the Application. You shouldn't have any problems instantiating additional routers after calling `Backbone.history.start()` (at least according to [this answer from BB.Marionette's Derick Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712734/backbone-multiple-routers-and-history-start))